# What is the meaning of the value set by CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, libcurl

I'm trying to verify a server's certificate before obtaining data from it using https. I'm assuming that after `curl_easy_perform` I should use:

```
long out = -1;
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT, &out)
```

I cannot find any documentation explaining the meaning of the value `out` is set to, except for an example on https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT.html, which seems to be wrong (or at least contradicts my experiments).

This example suggests that the value `0` means verification failure, while any other value signifies success.
I found that `0` is actually set every time I get a response body and a sensible HTTP code (obtained using `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE`), whereas other values I've received (1 and 19) always went together with HTTP code 0 and empty body.

Am I missing something obvious or is there no documentation for `CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the documentation is missing that indeed. Issue filed: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/2400

Answer (score 0):

The value depends on the TLS backend used (OpenSSL, GnuTLS, etc).

It doesn't seem to work for Windows SCHANNEL at all.